# How to make a https request from Angular2 without proceeding not trusted certificate page

Tags: java, angular, ssl, spring-boot, https

I'm struggling to make a https request from my Angular2 app to my Springboot app, both apps are deployed on Cloud and urls are like "https://backend.example.com" and "https://frontend.example.com". When I want to get/post some data from BackEnd It is not working unless I do it manually and pushing proceed anyway button. Is there any way to handle it pragmatically?

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working? What do you mean by do it manually?. Show some examples. Your question  title and body don't seem to have a connection. The body is meant to explain in detail what's in the title.

Comment: when I'm running my front-end app on cloud, http requests to server are not working because server is using ssl and certificate is not trusted. By manually I mean I  write back-end url  on address bar and then I'll see the "certificate is not trusted" page, I'm pushing "proceed anyway" button, afterwards all the requests from my front-end app will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you use the valid SSL certificate then will not be encountered that warnings.

Second, you can send all your requests from browser to one Reverse Proxy server (Apache HTTP server or Nginx) and it will redirect them to the right server (in your case one for your Front-end Application and one for Bcck-end Application)

This case has been mentioned as one usage of Reverse Proxy [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy).

Hope it can help